# Scala Method Mirror return Type is always Any

Tags: scala, reflection

I am new to Scala. So how could I solve the problem that method mirror always returns Any?

```
class ABC{
    def getString(): String = {
        return "a,b,c";
    }
}

//somewhere in the project
val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader);
val c = Class.forName("ABC");
val classSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(c);
val classType = classSymbol.toType;
val im = mirror.reflect(c.newInstance())
val _method_ = classType.declaration(ru.newTermName("getString")).asMethod;
val method = im.reflectMethod(_method_);
println(method()); //this prints "a,b,c"
println(method().length()); // error, value length is not a member of any
```

Can I get the proper function that returns the proper object instead of Any? Thank you!
If the method mirror cannot return the proper object(Like String), then what is the point of method mirror?

Comment: This is the same behavior as the java reflection api. A Method instance will return an instance of Object always when invoked.  I don't think the behavior you seek exists.  These reflection class types are not setup with generics to allow the proper return type to be returned when invoked.

Comment: @cmbaxter: this is not related to generics; this is a fundamental limitation (although I'm even reluctant to call it a limitation)—there is no way in the universe to make dynamically reflected entities have static types.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for runtime reflection to return objects with proper static types because static types are only applicable at compilation time (hence *static* types); in order to enforce a dynamically created object to have the desired static type, you have to do a manual cast to whatever type you need and know will be returned at runtime.

So either:

```
val ret = method().asInstanceOf[String].length
```

or

```
val typedMethod = () => method().asInstanceOf[String]

val ret = typedMethod().length // ret will be 5
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to cast the `method` object to the appropriate function type directly (unless I'm missing something here):

```
method.asInstanceOf[() => String]
```

will raise at runtime

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaVanillaMethodMirror cannot be cast to scala.Function0
```

and

```
(method.apply _).asInstanceOf[() => String]
```

will raise at runtime

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: test$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function0
```